# How to change or redirect home page to customer login?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, redirect, home-page

Need to see customer account at the first before home page. used redirect from the admin panel but not working. Still, when I load my site it goes to the home page.

Mean that see customer account login instead of the home page.[image]

Comment: did you reindex and recache your website after the changes as your system config are cached

Comment: Yes i am, but still shoes home page

Comment: In your admin under the system config. id suggest you changing all store views to make sure that the config is still is the same for each view

Answer (score 1):

> Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
      </type>
    </config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/'); // Change the path to where you need to redirect
        return $result;
    }

}
```

> Vendor/Module/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module",
    "description": "Redirect homepage to customer login",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more? should i create a module?

Comment: Yes, create a module and use this after plugin.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please give me full structure of it to create?

Comment: MGPM, check my updated code and let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: Thanks, i created module with edited that i post. run commands, but still see home page! on path used $result->setPath('customer/account/login'); instead of / .